# How to fetch all the XHR's header data using python/selenium/robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need to fetch all the API's request URL from a web page while browsing it
can anyone help me with this?

the aim is to compare the list of API which is being called and supposed to call

I tried using a driver.get_log("performance") selenium method but I am getting only .jpgs and png files

```
driver.get("https:<URL>")

logs = driver.get_log("performance")
# Opens a writable JSON file and writes the logs in it
with open("network_log.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("[")

    # Iterates every logs and parses it using JSON
    for log in logs:
        network_log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
        f.write(json.dumps(network_log)+",")
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late for this, but I recently had a similar situation, and by setting this configuration for my chrome driver, I was able to get all XHR:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
import json
import os

chromedriver_path = f'{os.getcwd()}//chromedriver.exe'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-single-click-autofill")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view[8]")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {"performance": 'ALL'}

driver_obj = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

logs = [json.loads(log["message"])["message"] for log in driver_obj.get_log("performance")]
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Selenium doesn't handle anything like that. You would need to use a proxy with selenium like browsermob or something else that would let you intercept all network requests.